# Authenticate mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-internal-auth

I have 4 instances of mongodb running(replica set) with following `mongodb.conf` file for each instance:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /root/mongodata/log/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /root/mongodata/db1 # also have db2 and so on for rest of the instances
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /root/mongodata/db1/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile, different for 4 instances

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 30000 #port different for 4 different instances
  bindIp: 12.123.321.432(example ip, same for all 4 .conf files) 

# security  
security:
  KeyFile: /path to my keyfile location

#  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: testReplica #have this same for all 4


#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I also created a keyfile for internal authentication as follows:

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > <path-to-keyfile>
chmod 400 <path-to-keyfile>
```

After all the instances are running I opened mongoShell as follows:

```
mongo --host 12.123.321.432 --port 30000
```

I am able to open the shell but when I try to create a user, I get the following exception:

```
2016-12-22T20:55:38.396-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on test to execute command { createUser: "root", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 30000.0 } } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1230:11
@(shell):1:1
```

I tried switching to admin db but still says unauthorized, I also tried to run rs.initiate() command to define primary and secondary dbs, says unauthorized. I read even if i start the `mongod` with authentication disabled the internal authentication via `keyfile` will force the role based authentication. What am I missing here and how would i resolve it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that you have not privileges to execute the command.

After set **keyfile** parameter in **.conf** file, mongo need you login with auth user.

So if you have not root user.

1. start mongod without auth config (don't set **keyfile** and disable  `security.authorization` )
2. create use with root role

```
db.createUser({user:"root",pwd:"rootpassword",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})
```

if you have root user, you should use `db.auth()` or login mongo with root privileges, for executing `rs.conf()` command.

```bash
mongo --port portnumber -u root -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

or after login with command **mongo --port portnumber**

```
db.auth("root", "rootpassword")
```

ps. KeyFile is for replica set inner communication security.

Comment: You are almost correct but for replica set the trick was to start with empty `db` folder and in `.conf` file you should not provide the`'keyFile` parameter. As soon as you put in `keyFile` internal authentication + role based access is forced. So start without `keyfile` and the create necessary users and then restart with `keyFile` added to `.conf` file. Note: when you provide `keyFile` parameter u dont need to use `--auth` to enable authentication. Please update your answer so that I can mark as correct answer. thanks!

Comment: @Gurkha yes, that's right, answer have updated, hope this help you.